# what is ideavim equivalent of "ctrl+w" Select successively increasing code blocks

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

what is the equivalent of `ctrl+w` that I use in intellij when using `ideavim`?
(and select successively decreasing...)

Answer (score 3):

I know it's old question, but for anybody interested. You can use `v` (visual mode) and then just use IDE's `ctrl + w` or `ctrl + shift + w` as suggested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-510#comment=27-1013342.

To make this work I had to go to `Settings > Other Settings > Vim Emulation` and set `IDE` as a handler for `Ctrl+W`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not supported at the moment (0.39), feel free to vote for [VIM-510](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-510).

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines to your .ideavimrc

```
nnoremap <leader>w v:action EditorSelectWord<CR>
vnoremap <leader>w :action EditorSelectWord<CR>
```